# jquery отправка файла

Tags: jquery

Есть форма с кодом:

```
 $j('.save').click(function (e) {
        var cont   = $j('.edit').serialize();
        $j.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/admin/edit.php',
          data: cont,
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Страница успешно изменена');
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    });
```

Как сделать чтобы файлы тоже отправлялись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую!

Вы таким образом файлы не отправите. Сериалайз не дает возможности отправить файл, вам нужно использовать FormData. Конечно, выполнить код вы не сможете в предлагаемом stackoverflow функционале, но скопировать себе сможете =)

```js
$(documen).ready(function(){
  $("form[name=SendFileForm]").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form[name=SendFileForm]')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/', //куда отправить данные
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function( respond ){
        // ожидаем json в формате {"success":true|false,"message":"сообщение"}
        if( respond.success ){
          alert(respond.message); // Файл загружен
        }
        else{
          alert( respond.message ); // Ошибки на стороне сервера
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="SendFileForm">
  <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <button type="submit">send file</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Хорошо бы еще упомянуть, что FormData только для IE10+

Comment: =) да нормально все, сейчас основное большинство браузеров поддерживают формдату. На крайний случай можно взять jquery.form . Неплохой пример http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/